# elements with display:block don't shown

Tags: javascript, html, css

I create my website with a wordpress template. I try to use a widget for showing products. but it widget shows with none item, I review it's HTML codes and I see that all items are in HTML source codes and Firebug show that in CSS of it is `display:block;`
it widget have  , 
I disable javascripts and wasn't useful.

[image]

my website url: http://asp-int.com/

it's in `<div class="sidebar-widget home-sidebar-widget products slider-container" id="products-widget-2">`

please help me

Comment: are you sure there are products in it? because I do see products in the box beneath it. if you check the codes, I can see the procuts are not on that box, they are far to the left out of the screen

Comment: yes, for example you can see `<span class="title"><a href="http://asp-int.com/?product=bloody-mary">Bloody Mary</a></span>` in source but don't shown

Comment: There is something wrong in `.slider .items {  position: relative; }`, remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the `position:relative` from `.slider .items`

```
.slider .items {
/*    position: relative;*/
}
```

I think this will solve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that `<div class="items">PRODUCTS</div>` has width 0. A possible solution is to add to the class `items` the CSS : `width : 100%`.

I tried doing it ad-hoc in chrome debugger, and it worked great.

Comment: It's slider and I can't set width to 100%

Comment: I see. Is the slider your development or an external component? If it's an external one, please provide a link.

Comment: Eshan, I've played with it for a while, and the problem lies with the width (not specifically the 100%). The width is extremely high (20000em). Setting it to 2000px improves the situation, but you say you can't adjust it. Could you show us a bit more what can you control there?